# Display custom information in App settings of UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am building a UWP application. When I open the app settings for my App, I see a window like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztTRy.png)

I want to display some more information on this window. I want to display if the app is in beta version or debug version or release version on this window.

Is this achievable? Can I get custom information displayed on this window for my UWP app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible today. Please submit a feature suggestion here:

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/